# What is the purpose of onCanceled() in Android Loader

Tags: android, android-loadermanager, android-loader

I have implemented a `Loader` where in `onStopLoader`(), I have called `cancelLoad`() method. However despite the above call, `onCanceled`() is not getting called. What is the purpose of this callback?

On pressing the home button in my Activity, I can see `onStop`() for Activity is getting called and further `onStopLoading`() for Loader is also getting called.

```
@Override
public void onStopLoading() {
   super.onStopLoading();
   cancelLoad();
   Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onStopLoading()");
}

@Override
public void onCanceled(List<Earthquake> earthquakes) {
   super.onCanceled(earthquakes);
   Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onCancelled()");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> [cancelLoad()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html#cancelLoad()): Attempt to cancel the current load task. Must be called on the main
>   thread of the process.

Since, `onStopLoading()` is already invoked, there is nothing to cancel anymore, thus the callback `onCanceled()` is never invoked.

See, what the documentation says about the return value of `cancelLoad()`

> Returns false if the task could not be canceled, typically because it
>   has already completed normally [...]

So, in your case it should return false because it already stopped.

Comment: @SumitTrehan did it help?